# animation() and opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, opacity, jquery-animate

cant make this animation to work

```
var highlight = $('<div class="insert_highlight" style="top:25px; left:100px; width:50px; height:50px"></div>').appendTo($(document.body))
    .animate({
            opacity : 0.1
        },
        400);

div.insert_highlight {
    position:absolute;
    background:#00ff00;
    z-index:-1;
    /*display:none;*/
}
```

as it is now the opacity fades down from 1 to 0.1, but if I unescape the `display:none;` in the style nothing happens and the element stays at opacity 0 or display:none

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var highlight = $('<div class="insert_highlight" style="top:25px; left:100px; width:50px; height:50px"></div>').appendTo($(document.body))
    .css({display: 'block', opacity:0})
    .animate({
            opacity : 0.1
        },
        400);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u72Bt/2/)

I used:

```
var highlight = $('<div class="insert_highlight" style="top:25px; left:100px; width:50px; height:50px"></div>').appendTo($(document.body))
    .css('display','none') // set css to hide element
    .fadeTo(400 , 0.1);   // and finally go to desired opacity
```

Comment: -10 ahah..:P btw, yeah I can understand your opinion (and I meant, instead of adding 'for fun' maybe explain why). And..for the OP..It'd be better to make a longer transition and to a value bigger than 0.1 ;)

Comment: Aaaaaargh I reedited my demo that has all of the mentioned! never mind, clarkk does not like fadeTo ;)

Answer (score 0):

`display:none` means that the element won't be rendered by the browser...what do you want to achieve? You'll have to set `display:block` to see it

Comment: have also tried with visibility:hidden.. but the result is the same.. Im just used to use display:none because it works (but not in this example)

Comment: but do u want the element to disappear at the end of the animation? or to start from transparent and become opaque?

Comment: it has to be transparent from the beginning

Comment: ok just set css (by jquery's css method) opacity:0 and display:block BEFORE starting the animation ;)

Answer (score 0):

that's the problem itself.

display:none is not equal to opacity:0;

if an element is 100% transparent, it's still "visible" in the means of CSS.

give it

```
opacity:0; /*(for css3 supporting browsers) and*/ 
filter:alpha(opacity=0); /*for IE 6-8 and */
-ms-filter:alpha(opacity=0); /*for ie9*/
```

that should do the trick

Comment: isnt there a "quicker" solution?

Comment: ie sucks, but it works. For the sake of standards compliance, you should put yhose filter stuff in different css files and link them with conditional comments

Comment: @beerwin:  Why add CSS rules for opacity? The OP is using jQuery which nicely takes care of cross-browser opacity issues.

Comment: yes, it does, but IMHO, it wouldn't be a good thing to increase the load on the visitor's computer any further. I'm using javascript for this purpose as a last resort.

this is my opinion, not wanting to push it down on anyone's throat

Comment: @beerwin:  Increase load?  jQuery is already loaded and running animations.  Having it take care of cross-browser CSS opacity issues is part of its job and nearly inconsequential compared the alternative issue... calling various browser specific CSS files called via conditional comments.

Comment: @Sparky672: 
That goes OK with a few elements, but not with a hundred.
I'm assuming not everybody has quad-core cpu-s and 8 gigs of RAM. (Sorry if i'm too much concerned about visitors, but they are the primary source of my income and that comes __through my web site__, and many of my clients know that as well).

Comment: @beerwin: Your sarcasm is unnecessary here.  For visitor's sake, one should really examine the necessity of a hundred jQuery animated elements on a single web page.

Comment: @Sparky672: First, i'm sorry if i offended you or anybody else here. You're right, but unfortunately there are many sites which aren't going this way. __And as i said in my second comment _IMHO_, that's my opinion, and not a law you have to obey to__. I finished on my end.